# node-http-proxy return content is blank

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

I have a https proxy to an apache server
The apache server is behind the node proxy at https://localhost:444

```
var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
    sslproxy.web(req, res, {
        target: "https://localhost:444"
    });
}).listen(443);
```

When I use the browser to browse, the content rendered ok. However, if I use something like redleg fileviewer https://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/ or fetch by google to fetch the page, the content is empty like:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   date: Wed, 20 Dec 2017 22:05:33 GMT
>   server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
>   set-cookie: ct_cookies_test=aeeeadff0ae23e02715de88576a89e37; path=/
>   x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
>   content-length: 0
>   connection: close
>   content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Any thoughts about why content-length return 0, but use browser rendering is okay?

Answer (score 0):

I saw "x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN" in the response, so I guess CORS is the correct answer.